# Remove duplicates from a column R

Tags: r, duplicates, row-removal

I have a long column (9500 rows in excel), where I have a lot of gene ids. I want to remove the duplicates.

```
ID
BXDC2                     
BXDC5                   
BXDC5                     
BZRPL1                    
BZRPL1                                       
C10orf11         
C10orf116                                 
C10orf119              
C10orf120    
C10orf125          
C10orf125
```

And I want the result to be:

```
ID
BXDC2                     
BXDC5                                      
BZRPL1                    
C10orf11         
C10orf116                                 
C10orf119              
C10orf120    
C10orf125
```

Can anybody help me with an R script :-)?

Comment: Kind of ironic... removing duplicates is a duplicate :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `duplicated` or `unique`. Here, I am assuming that the column name is 'ID'

```
 df1[!duplicated(df1$ID),,drop=FALSE]
```

Or

```
  library(data.table)#v1.9.4+
  unique(setDT(df1), by='ID')
```